# Cannot create New Database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Anyone please give me some ideas what to do next? I have a 2008 SQL Server installed, and try to create a DB on my PC `\SQLExpress`, however, I come up with the following message:

> Cannot write property isfilestream this property is not available on sql server 7.0

Actually I have already enabled this via the properties within Management Studio and via the configuration tool, but the message still pops out...

My computer originally has 2008, but because I cannot access to the local server .\SQLExpress, then I re-downloaded the 2012 SQL Server, and then is able to access to the local server via 2008 SQL management studio. Not sure if this is related to my issue

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx You cannot enable FILESTREAM on a 32-bit version of SQL Server running on a 64-bit operating system. Is this the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I downloaded the 64-bit version, and my laptop is 64-bit. However, I forgot to mention that my computer originally has 2008, but because I cannot access to the local server .\SQLExpress, then I re-downloaded the 2012 SQL Server, and then is able to access to the local server via 2008 SQL management studio. Not sure if this is related to my issue.

Comment: edit you question to add those details, still you aren't sure about it's related or not...

Comment: Thanks for all the answer, I just download the 2012 management studio and now it works, looks like it is the incompatibility of 2008 management studio and 2012 configuration tool that caused my problem